# windows service installation failed rollback has been performed

Tags: c#, windows-services

While Installing the Windows Service As an Administrator I am prompted to set Service Login!

As I Set it, I am Getting error that Installation failed And Rollback has been Permormed.

Error I am getting Is same as this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7cea376a-cab5-497a-927d-0c224e58053b/service-application-installation-fail?forum=winformssetup

But running visual Studio Command Promt as an administrator cannot solve this problem.That's why I'm repeating question.
I am Newbie to this platform so unaware of issue.

Comment: are you using event log??

Comment: if you see then the exception is already given in command prompt before rollback has performed

Comment: No, I haven't used event log

Comment: I am getting this: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : No mapping between Account names and Security Ids.

Comment: There are plenty of discussions related to "No mapping between Account names and Security Ids" on msdn - please check is one of proposed solution would work for you.

Comment: The Error has been resolved by Changing Log-on Property of Service. Thank you..

Comment: This did me realize I should've used the command prompt as administrator! :D

Answer (score 0):

Error was with Service Login. So, I changed the Login Property of the service from **User Account** to **Local System Account**, which resolved my problem.